# how get result from View in ViewModel in MVVMLight (the call chain starts from ViewModel)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a situation in which my view should do something related to UI (for example serializing UI layout or a COM call ,...) I want to send a message and get that calculation from my UI in my ViewModel.So how can I get an output from a message send?

1- Using a callback method as the parameter of Message and call back it from the view.

2- Put a property in ViewModel and set this property in response to the message call in View.

I prefer the first one,is it right? any other way?

Seems it was not clear but call chain starts in ViewModel means I need to simulate something like a function call form ViewModel to view and get the result of this call.

Comment: you can write a code from your code behind (this.DataContext as yourViewmodel).yourmethod

Comment: @DhavalPatel call starts from ViewModel

Comment: Then you can use messaging service when call start from Viewmodel you have to bordcast message and register that message.

Comment: @DhavalPatel I already know about it the question is how can I get result from my message broadcast back?

Comment: yes you can get it what's the prob in it?

Comment: could you put a sample how I can return some information from a message handler in MVVMLight?

Comment: I have added a sample how to use message service.

Answer (score 2):

I would do very simple here: just call a method of your ViewModel from your View.

---

EDIT:

I'm not a big fan of messaging in MVVM, I often prefer events. So the simple approach I would use is:

- The ViewModel exposes a public event.
- The View attaches a handler to the event of the ViewModel.
- The ViewModel raises the event
- The View executes the handler (code-behind) and either:

  - call a public method of the ViewModel
  - call a callback contained in the EventArgs parameter of the event handler

If you don't like events and prefer messaging, that's the same: it's callback vs public method/property (here I will always prefer *method* vs *property setter* because I don't like adding hard logic and exception management in a setter).

So to answer the question: I would go for the public method which is simpler IMO.

Comment: The problem is that the ViewModel start the call chain, the process starts from VM

Answer (score 1):

For accessing active-X/COM controls I tend to have a control reference on the VM which gets set by the view in code behind when the control has loaded. The VM can then call any methods directly.

Not ideal but Active-X doesn't fit well with MVVM since it encompasses both view and logic.

Comment: just not for COMs 
but generally seems there is not any other good way to simulate a function call with return value in MVVM

Comment: That's because you shouldn't really be doing it. The whole point of MVVM is that the VM knows nothing about the view implementation.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer Well you do want the kind of communication the OP is asking for. The most basic use case is the confirmation pop-up.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer In my opinion  there are needs for this communication in some parts and also we should note that it is a ModelView not model and messaging concepts came to support these needs but still seems messaging concepts does not have solution for all kinds this kind of ViewModel-View call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Messaging service like

declare one class

```
public class HandleClass
{
  public object Obj{get;set;}
  public  HandleClass(object _obj)
  {
   Obj=_obj;
   }
}
```

Now Send the Message From your ViewModel

```
Messanger.Default.Send<HandleClass>(new HandleClass(){Obj=AssignedValue});
```

Now Received the Message from where you want the object information

```
Messanger.Default.Register<HandleClass>(this,ReceivedInformation)
private Void ReceivedInformation(HandleClass handle)
{
you can get the Obj object with full of information you can access like
var abc=handle.Obj;
}
```

Comment: This how I can send message,  But I want information back from message handler, a return value

Comment: Then you can use Callback